# Initialize a Python object from command line input

Tags: python, class, input, command-line

I'm new to Python and am learning input/output.  Right now, I'm trying to add attributes to an object from a file that I specify from command line input.

For example, I want to run the following: `$ /...filepath.../ python3 myCode.py < 06` to pass the contents of file `06`

```
$ /...filepath.../ cat 06
7
4 5 2 7 88 2 1
```

to `myCode.py`. Both `myCode.py` and `06` are located in the same directory.

I'm trying to create a `MyClass` object from a command line call with attributes to be as follows:

```
## myCode.py ##

# create class
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
    self._num_one = int(sys.stdin.readline())    
    self._num_many = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readline().split()]

# print attributes
print(MyClass()._num_many)
print(MyClass()._num_one)
```

but I'm getting the following error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` for `self._num_one` but am able tor print `self._num_many` and am not sure why.  If I swap the order of `self._num_one` and `self.num_many`, then I can get `self._num_one`. Since `06` is only two lines long, is there a first line that I'm not initially reading?  Why can I only print one of the two attributes, and how would I print both?

Many thanks.

Comment: It's generally considered bad design to have complex operations, such as IO, in a class initializer. In this case, every time you want to create a new object will read from stdin. That makes testing it much more difficult. Better to use a "factory function" to read stdin, parse the input, and then instantiate the class with proper types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your code that stops it from working.

First thing first, you need to remove whitespace before and after if you are reading the input file one line after another. This means a call to the `.strip()` method after `.readline()`. You are getting the `ValueError` because `int()` cannot process non-numeric string.

```
>>> int('x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'x'
>>> int(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
>>> int('\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\n'
>>> int('1')
1
```

So the code becomes

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._num_one = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
        self._num_many = [int(x) for x in sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()]
```

Secondly, whenever you do `MyClass()` it instantiates a new object. If I understand the code correctly, it is expecting to read two lines **twice** (4 lines in total). Given the input file, I am assuming you are interested in instantiating **ONE** object. Therefore we instantiate one, and tag it to a variable, then use that reference later.

```
instantiatedObject = MyClass()
print(instantiatedObject._num_many)
print(instantiatedObject._num_one)
```

Answer (score 0):

just because your input stream is not an int, it's a string with space and "\n" delimiter, you have to work on these things first.

The quick and easy way is changing your code to something like this (not tested):

```
self._num_one = int("".join(sys.stdin.readline().split()))
```